# What is the temperature range for eggplants? Why can't I get fruit?

Tags: fruits, eggplant

I live in Orlando, Fl. I planted these plants in late February and they started to flower two months later and no fruit.
I have tried the paintbrush way to pollinate the plants.
I've tried the tapping way.
Also took one flower off and rubbed it on other flowers from different plants.

I have 5 plants from 3 different sources.

The plants are all around 3-5' tall and very bushy and tons of flowers, they get great sun and I give them fish fertilizer once a month. They get watered once a day in the early AM by drip nozzles (each plant it's own nozzle). I give then pellet fertilizer every two months.

The plants are growing well and getting bigger every day. But no fruit.
The plants are outside in a new raised bed, and get great sun.

What am I doing wrong that I can't get fruit.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: +1 awesome and exciting question that can only be improved with a photo. Please report back in an year or two how You solved it! I stand by the answer below that too much nitrogen is being applied. Possibly.

Answer (score 3):

We don't do anything, they just fruit.  I think that you are overfertilising them (especially Nitrogen).

According to [Why Do Eggplants Have Flowers but No Fruits?](https://www.yourindoorherbs.com/why-eggplants-have-flowers-but-no-fruits/#:%7E:text=There%20are%203%20general%20reasons,not%20cost%20the%20gardener%20much.) there are 4 reasons

> There are 3 general reasons why eggplants produce flowers but bear no fruits:
>
> 1. incorrect watering,
> 2. failure to self-pollinate,
> 3. over-fertilization of the soil, and
> 4. less than optimal weather.
>
> It might look daunting but these problems are fairly easy to solve and do not cost the gardener much.